# Set multiple alarms every every day a week

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, schedule

I am working on an app, I store schedules on everyday basis, eg there will be 6 schedule each day but timming will be different for each day, I have stored Scheduled and there timings  in sqlite in a table, Now i want to make alarm for these schedules, How should i do so.
The alarms be like eg, for sunday 9:30 am, 10:40 am, 11:00 am , 12 pm, 4 pm, 5pm and for monday 7 am , 8am etc.
I am using this code to set alarm on specific time

```
    calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, week);
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuts);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calSet.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: I have save the time in sqlite in string format, hour minute and format(am pm) has separate columns, and they are selected from spinner, i havn't used time picker.

Comment: But not know how this code will make alarm when application is not open, and hours and minutes come from sqlite database,

Comment: Also i have to set six alarms each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use SQlite then it's very easy, 
you can use PendingIntent with different request code.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), requestcode, intent, 0);
requestcode+=1;
```

I have posted 3 classes using these classes you can get your task.

**SetAlarms.java** class actually set alarm

```
 public class SetAlarms {
        Context c;
        String SaveStateVal;

        public SetAlarms(Context c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        public void AlarmSet(int i, Calendar targetCal) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(c, AlarmReciever.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, i, intent,
                    0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) c
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pendingIntent);

        }
    }
```

This is **AlarmReciever.java**  class when alarm is comes then this will be call

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MediaPlayer mP;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // /** Play sound */
        mP = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.tn);
        mP.start();

        // Show the toast like in above screen shot
        Toast.makeText(context, "Congratulation Alarm is Triggered",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Mainactivity.java** class you can provide value(time) to the alarm class  simply, using Timepacker you can set alarm.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TimePickerDialog tPickerDialog;
    SharedPreferences StatPref;
    TextView tvtime, sttime;
    Button setTim, getRec;
    SetAlarms ar;
    String str;
    int Count = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        StatPref = getSharedPreferences("mfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        reference();
        tvtime.setText(getStr());
        setTim.setOnClickListener(this);
        sttime.setOnClickListener(this);
        getRec.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void reference() {
        ar = new SetAlarms(this);
        sttime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sttime);
        getRec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updtTime);
        tvtime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tim);
        tvtime.setText(getStr());
        setTim = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sctime);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sctime:
            openTimePickerDialog(false);
            tvtime.setText(getStr());
            break;
        case R.id.sttime:
            openTimePickerDialog(false);
            break;
        case R.id.updtTime:
            tvtime.setText(getStr());
            break;
        }

    }

    private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        tPickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                onTimeSetListener, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), is24r);
        tPickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");
        tPickerDialog.show();
    }

    OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
                // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            // setAlarm(calSet);
            if (Count <= 6) {
                ar.AlarmSet(Count, calSet);
                str = "\n" + "Alarm " + Count + " Set " + calSet.getTime();
                Editor editrr = StatPref.edit();
                editrr.putString("ref" + Count, str);
                editrr.commit();
                Count++;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "Set 6 Alarms at Same Time Restart Your App",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    private String getStr() {
        str = StatPref.getString("ref1", "");
        str = str + "\n" + StatPref.getString("ref2", "");
        str = str + "\n" + StatPref.getString("ref3", "");
        str = str + "\n" + StatPref.getString("ref4", "");
        str = str + "\n" + StatPref.getString("ref5", "");
        str = str + "\n" + StatPref.getString("ref6", "");
        return str;
    }
}
```

**main.xml** for **MainActivity.java** class , use this xml as a layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Alarm Manager"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sttime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Set Time"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="220sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sctime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="scheduleAlarm"
            android:text="Schedule Alarm" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/updtTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Updated View" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save alarm time in database.
Don't set repeating alarm but a single one.
When your first alarm is triggered (when you receive the alarm event through broadcastreceiver) query the database, and set next alarm.

So the idea is simple - when you execute an alarm set the next alarm then. You have to implement the logic how to find the next alarm time.

Comment: Thanks StarDust. Basically i am not repeating alarm, In my application user has to set six times a day and that will be saved in SQLITE. Then on the basis of these times six alarms will be trigged per day.

Comment: when an alarm will be triggered, make a sql query, get the next alarm time, set the alarm at that time.
e.g. if you set first alarm at 9.30am, when it will be triggered at 9.30am, make a sql query, get the next alarm time (10.40am) and set the next alarm.